# Configure an AsyncCallback method with StreamSocket Input Stream

Tags: uwp, tcpclient

I am modifying some code that is based on TCPClient in order to get it to work with UWP.  I am trying to replace the TCPClient infrastructure with one based on StreamSocket.  The problem I am running into is a replacement for this:

```
            client.GetStream().BeginRead(readBuffer, 0, READ_BUFFER_SIZE, new AsyncCallback(FetchFrame), null);
```

I can't find an equivalent method for StreamSocket that allows me to set up an asynchronous callback function (in this case FetchFrame) for reading the input stream.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

> I can't find an equivalent method for StreamSocket that allows me to set up an asynchronous callback function (in this case FetchFrame) for reading the input stream.

As far as I know there is no way to set up an asynchronous call back function for StreamSocket input stream. [TCPClient.GetStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a [NetworkStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream(v=vs.110).aspx) object, which doesn't exist in UWP.

But since the callback executed after the `BeginRead` completes. We can do it in UWP way. You can first get the input stream by following codes:

```
Stream streamIn = socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead();//socket is a StreamSocket instance
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(streamIn);
string response = await reader.ReadLineAsync();
```

After this you can call your `FetchFrame` based on the result you got.

```
FetchFrame(response).
```

For details of using StreamSocket, please refer to [Sockets in UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/networking/sockets).

And there is also a greate official Sample to refer to: [StreamSocket](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/StreamSocket).

Notes:Different from Documentation, official Sample use a [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.aspx) to load the input stream.